# How to add a column to a csv using sed

Tags: csv, sed

I'm trying to add a column to the end of a csv that looks like this

```
id,date
123,2020-02-08
456,2020-01-94
456,2020-05-20
...
...
...
```

The first Row should be called `col_name`

The second row should be called `string`

and all the other rows should be have `test`

so the csv should end up as:

```
id,date,col_name
123,2020-02-08,string
456,2020-01-94,test
456,2020-05-20,test
...
...
...
```

Is there a way I can use sed or awk to make this happen?

Thanks

Comment: Please share your attempt to solve this

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I worked it out.

`sed '1s/$/,col_name/; 2s/$/,string/; 3,$s/$/,TEST/' filename.csv`

My actual problem is how excel is saving the file in a wierd format, i'll open another question about this.